# php math plus don't remove zeros

Tags: php, math

PLease look my php code. I dont want rmeoving zeros.

```
<?php
$number = '00154';
$next = $number + 1;
echo $next; // returns 155
?>
```

But I want to return **00155**

Comment: You'll need to be careful with numbers left-padded by zeroes, they will be interpreted in octal (8-base).

Comment: They won't since it's _string_. PHP will treat octal only for plain form, i.e. `0154` is decimal 108 (since will be treated as octal) while `'0154'` is 154 as integer (because won't be treated as octal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str_pad) in conjunction with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen). `strlen()` gets the number of digits, and then uses that as the pad length for `str_pad()`.

```
$next = str_pad($next, strlen($number), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

If you always want a fixed length, say 5, then this becomes shorter:

```
$next = sprintf('%05d', $next);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133203)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with [str_pad](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) if your number length is constant. In your case you have 5 length number. You can get length of number first and you can fill up zeros in result;

```
<?php
$number = '00154';
$length = strlen($number);
$next = $number + 1;
echo str_pad($next, $length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
```

Here is a working demo: **[codepad](http://codepad.org/YDhQLKzd)**

Answer (score 1):

`00155` and `155` is from a maths perspective **EQUAL**.

```
echo str_pad($next, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

fills left side with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your number is a string. Convert it to a number (integer or float) first, the use math function.